# best way to set a 1px height for empty div row in css div table?

Tags: html, css, layout

I've created a css div table (display: table, table-row, table-cell). On one of the rows (div display:table-row) I'd like to set the height to 1px. I tried line-height:1px but it looks like this style is only applied if I include some type of text within the div like &nbsp. However, if I include &nbsp in the div, it appears that a minimum line-height of approx 10px is applied. Is there an approach that I can use within this div table to achieve a 1px height of this div?

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the followings:

```
style = "max-height: 1px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding zero font size to the specific row will help to remove space.

```
div.empty-div-row {
  font-size: 0;
}
```